# jQuery: Split text at mouse-click position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouse

I'm trying to program something like a textarea, just for training.

I have a div with (user-generated) text in it:

```
<div id="editor">Hello! I am a Text!</div>
```

If I click (with left mousebutton) between the two "L" of "Hello", for example, I'd like to see this:

```
<div id="editor">Hel<div id="cursor">|</div>lo! I am a Text!</div>
```

How do I achieve this? Until now, I'm doing it with...

```
//HTML
<div id="editor" onclick="setCursorWithMouse()"><!-- User-Text --></div>

//jQuery
function setCursorWithMouse(){
    $('#editor').append('<div id="cursor">|</div>');
}
```

...but, of course, it just adds the cursor at the end of the div.

How can I know where exactly the user clicked, where to add my cursor (or whatever), where to split the text?

Thanks

Edit:

- I do not want to use contenteditable! Just look at it this way: I want to split a string at the mouse-click position.
- I know .append() is not what I'm looking for! .append() was just a Placeholder for a later, better, function. THIS function I'm right now asking for.
- I use a fixed-width font.

Comment: It looks like you want to create your own text-editor. For that you should have a look at [html's contenteditable](https://www.google.com/?q=html%20contenteditable#q=html+contenteditable)

Comment: I know contenteditable, but I'd rather do it without it. I would like to program the functionality of a textarea or a div with contenteditable by myself, that's what it's all about...

Comment: what good is `append()` when you want to change structure of existing html? Use contenteditable since your skills are not enough to do what you are asking

Comment: If you want to do it, you have to experiment a lot... So you can start with the mouse-position via `$().click(function (e) {})` and then e.clientX / e.clientY. Then you have to do a bit Maths and compare textlengths (in px; e.g. 'example' => 'e', 'ex', 'exa'...) with the mouseposition.

Comment: Can a fixed-width font be assumed?

Comment: Yes i use a fixed-width font

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is as close as I could get: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xk01b10q/3/)**

```
var clicked=false;
$('#editor').click(function(e){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var letterWidth=7;
    $('#editor span').remove();
    var clickPos=e.pageX-$(this).offset().left;
    if(!clicked) clickPos+letterWidth;
    var letter=Math.round(clickPos/letterWidth);
    var before=$(this).html().substr(0,letter);
    var after=$(this).html().substr(letter,$(this).html().length);
    $(this).html(before+'<span>|</span>'+after);
    clicked=true;
});
$(document).click(function(e){
    if(!$('#editor').is(e.target)){
        $('#editor').removeClass('active');
        $('#editor span').remove();
        clicked=false;
    }
});
```

I hope it's close enough! :)

**NOTE:**

this code is written assuming that the `font-size` is `16px`!

I'm afraid you have to calculate the `font-size` for further expansions.

Comment: This looks nice! I'll try to implement it into my code now, this may take a while. I'll come back then and you may get the "accepted answer" then. Thanks!

Comment: @AminJafari Nice ! +1

Answer (score 0):

Note, does not return expected results at firefox ; chrome returns expected results , though cursor may move to either left or right by 1 character , if mouse not released slowly.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).data("text", $("#editor").text())
    .on("mousedown", function() {
      $("#editor")
        .html($(this)
          .data("text"))
    })
    .on("mouseup", function() {
      that = $("#editor");
      var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection();
      var o = that.text();
      var before = sel.baseOffset;
      var after = o.length - before;
      var a = o.slice(0, before);
      var b = after === 0 ? "" : o.slice(-after);
      var n = "<data>|</data>";
      var html = (after === "" ? a + n : a + n + b);
      that.html(html);
    });
})
```

```css
#editor {
  font-family: Sans;
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  white-space: pre;
}
#editor > data {
  color: red;
  max-width: .1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div tabindex="0" id="editor">Hello! I am a Text!</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/maakff7q/

Comment: Please check your fiddle again. It just duplicates the existing text with a ` | ` between the phrases.

Comment: @crashwap See OP at _"If I click (with left mousebutton) between the two "L" of "Hello", for example, I'd like to see this:
<div id="editor">Hel<div id="cursor">|</div>lo! I am a Text!</div>"_ . If interpret Question correctly , requirement to insert `|`  where click within text , at position where clicked , simulating a `cursor` ? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like your interpretation of the OP is correct: the `|` char should be inserted into the existing phrase, at the point where user clicks. BUT, in your fiddle, cursor is inserted at end of phrase, and phrase is then duplicated exactly (creating two copies of orig phrase, separated by `|`. *Perhaps you are seeing something else when you run the fiddle? (Yet, how could that be?)* Compare visual output with accepted answer's DEMO fiddle. ***(This might explain why your otherwise excellent answer has not been upvoted...)***

Comment: @crashwap See updated post , included "Stack Snippets" (see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/2801559) . Not certain how / why different results appear at jsfiddle ? Same results at updated post as described above ? Thanks

Comment: Mystery solved -- it's a browser issue. I am using Firefox -- try it in FFox. (You are right; Chrome works correctly)